# How to do scraping in BeautifulSoup using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape an xml file using the following code which works perfectly fine:-

```
    f = open("sample_data.xml", "r")
    contents = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features="xml")
    for component in soup.find_all("component"):
        for section in component.find_all("section"):
            for entry in section.find_all("entry"):
                for encounter in entry.find_all("encounter"):
                    for participant in encounter.find_all("participant"):
                        for participantRole in participant.find_all("participantRole"):
                            for playingEntity in participantRole.find_all("playingEntity"):
                                for name in playingEntity.find_all("name"):
                                    print(name.text)
```

But instead of using so many for loops I would like to put it in a recursion. For this purpose I have created a list which will serve as our traversal path to find the desired element like below:-

```
traversal_path = ['component', 'section', 'entry', 'encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']
```

And to serve as a breakpoint for our recursive function we can use the traversal path's last item which in our case is `name`. As we go on itreating over the `traversal_path` the first item from the list gets removed until only one last item remains. According to this now my function has become like this:-

```
f = open("sample_data.xml", "r")
contents = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, features="xml")
traversal_path = ['component', 'section', 'entry', 'encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']

def rec(traversal_path, soup):
    print(traversal_path)
    if len(traversal_path) == 1:
        for last_item in soup.find_all(traversal_path[0]):
            print(last_item.text)
    else:
        t = traversal_path.pop(0)
        for first_item in soup.find_all(t):
            return rec(traversal_path, first_item)

rec(traversal_path, soup)
```

The output that I get is just the traversal path getting printed like below:-

```
['component', 'section', 'entry', 'encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']
['section', 'entry', 'encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']
['entry', 'encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']
['encounter', 'participant', 'participantRole', 'playingEntity', 'name']
```

When I print the `soup` instead of the `traversal_path` I get the output soup printed only until `entry`.

Also the problem in my function seems to be in the else part where it is not going into the recursion. Any help in the matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def rec(traversal_path, soup):
    if len(traversal_path) == 1:
        for last_item in soup.find_all(traversal_path[0]):
            print(last_item.text)
    else:
         try:
            for first_item in soup.find_all(traversal_path[0]):
                rec(traversal_path, first_item)
            t = traversal_path.pop(0)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

rec(field['traversal_path'].split(" "), soup)
```

Just remove return statement and handle the exceptions